# How to fix Error Code 1 on PhoneGap FileTransfer()

Tags: android, cordova

I'm newbie in PhoneGap App Developing.
Using *Android 4.1.2* with *cordova-2.6.0*.
What is wrong here?
Can anyone help me doing this....

```
    function photoDownload(url, target) {
    var url = encodeURI(url);
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
        var imagePath = fs.root.fullPath + "/" + target; // full file path
        // fs.root.fullPath returns "file:///storage/sdcard0/"
        //var imagePath = "/storage/sdcard0/" + target; // try another full file path
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(
            url,
            imagePath,
            function (entry) {
                alert("success" + entry.fullPath); // entry is fileEntry object
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("error source " + error.source);
                alert("error target " + error.target);
                alert("error code "   + error.code);
            },
            true,
            {
                headers: {}
            }
        );
    })
}
```

It returns error code 1 which means FILE NOT FOUND.
But I tried every way I could.

```
<div style="font-size: 22px;" onclick="photoDownload('url', 'save');">Download</div><br/><br/>

<div style="font-size: 22px;" onclick="photoDownload('http://aponblog.com/inc/images/globe.png', 'globe.png');">Download</div><br/>
<div style="font-size: 22px;" onclick="photoDownload('http://aponblog.com/inc/images/globe.png', 'TestFolder/globe.png');">TestFolder/Download</div><br/><br/>

<div style="font-size: 22px;" onclick="photoDownload('https://graph.facebook.com/simplyapon/picture?width=100&height=100', 'simplyapon.jpg');">S Download</div><br/>
<div style="font-size: 22px;" onclick="photoDownload('https://graph.facebook.com/simplyapon/picture?width=100&height=100', 'TestFolder/simplyapon.jpg');">S TestFolder/Download</div><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this my own! It had not enough permission to get FileSystem.
Thank You if you tried!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```